# Ordinary Annuity future value

Tags: arithmetic, finance

I have a problem to calculate future value of this problem:

"The parents of a newborn baby set up an account to cover the cost of college they deposited 1,500 every birthday in an account that pays 8%. When she get 12th, it increased to 3,000 per birthday."

I need calculate the amount available to her at age 18:

Future value from 0 to 11

$F_1=1500[\frac{(1+0.08)^{11}-1}{0.08}]=24,968.23$

Future value from 12 to before 18

$F_2=3000[\frac{(1+0.08)^{7}-1}{0.08}]=26,768.41$

but $F_1$ grow up from 12 to before 18 then:

$F_3=24,968.23(1+0.08)^{7}=42,791.16$

Then te amount available is $42,791.16+26,768.41= 69,559.57$

I don't understand why my in my book adds this:

$F_4=1500(1+0.08)^{18}=5,994.02$

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

From the question it is unclear if the parents deposited 1,500 on the day of birth. If they did that would explain $F_4$.

Comment: They deposited 1,500 on the day of birth!!! then I need to do F4. Thanks John!!!